Mrs. Square acquires another forest
An imaginary, but infamous, Lady landowner, nicknamed Mrs. Square, is, strange but true, specialized in owning, deploying and acquiring dense forest land property,
... only if square shaped ...,
anywhere around the world.
To accurately overlook land property area for sale, on each land property corner, she therefore requires seller to have placed a pole: in order to convince oneself, from the air, the land property shape is really square indeed.
Then, to exactly measure each land property size, and to calculate correct price, which is set fixed per square kilometer, Mrs. Square's engineers use powerful laser distance meters, from the ground up, measuring distances towards the required poles in place.
However, for several such dense forest land properties to be acquired, there are so many big trees, there is no way to laser measure between any of the four square corners at available height. Corners happen to simply pairwise not be in line of sight from the ground up to any useful height.
After sufficient time searching and trying on such land property, usually a lucky spot is found by Mrs. Square's experts, where three poles on the corners of the forest are in line of sight from the ground at appropriate height. The three distances from that spot to these three corners can then accurately be determined.
Question: What is such particular forest land property surface area, given those three measured figures from such spot?
Attribution: puzzle is based on similar questions, but, as far as I could track, either for specific figures, say (unlikely), 3 4 5, or, for limited general conditions, like (also unlikely), two of the three distances are equal.
a picture for reference (a b c are known distances)

Details:

 Question is based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5013127/ (with b=c) where I gave answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5013127/find-square-size-from-inscribed-triangles/5013553#5013553


 later I found related questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393130/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544719/



 Since Mrs. Square engineers already measured the distances, she already checked that the land property to be acquired is a square. Let $s$ be its side length. Put the origin of a Cartesian plane at the lower left corner of the square, such that its lower right and upper left corners have coordinates $(0,s)$  and $(s,0)$, respectively. Let $(x,y)$ be the coordinates of the spot, $A=a^2$, $B=b^2$, and $C=c^2$. Then we obtain the following system of the equations.


 $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=A\\(x-s)^2+y^2=B\\(x-s)^2+(y-s)^2=C\end{cases}.$$


 Subtracting the first equation from the second and the second from the third, we obtain $-2xs+s^2=B-A$ and $-2ys+s^2=C-A$. So $x=\frac{s^2+A-B}{2s}$ and $y=\frac{s^2+A-C}{2s}$. Plugging these values to the first equation, we obtain $$(s^2+A-B)^2+(s^2+A-C)^2=4As^2$$$$s^4-(B+C)s^2+\left(A^2-AB-AC+\frac{B^2+C^2}2\right)=0$$


 This is a quadratic equation for the land property area $S=s^2$ with the roots $$S=\frac{B+C\pm\sqrt{4AB+4AC+2BC-4A^2-B^2-C^2}}{2}.$$


Nice compact formula. I had a different, somewhat more geometric involved approach which I may want to refer to later. I verified a few examples giving same results. The right permutation you mention seems somewhat predictable and so far I always get first solution (+ from +/-) to be the correct one.

fwiw: the discriminant terms can be rearranged and factorized a little bit resulting in slightly shorter expression.

It seems like + corresponds to a survey point within the square, and - corresponds to a survey point outside the square.  I'm having trouble determining whether the puzzle excludes the latter case.

I get the incorrect answer when trying this out. $−2ys+s^2=C−A$ should be $−2ys+s^2=C−B$

@TomSirgedas : which particular triplet (a,b,c) did you try ?

$s = 10, x = 2, y= 4, A = 20, B = 80, C = 100$

$S = \frac{A+C\pm\sqrt{2AC+4AB+4BC-A^2-C^2-4B^2}}{2}$. Here $A$ and $C$ are interchangeable as expected.

(it's the same final answer, if $A$ and $B$ are swapped)

as original answer mentioned some permutation may be needed, and as I commented such permutation can be more or less predicted. Take A = 80 B = 100 C = 20 and get s=10. Typically biggest two numbers come first and biggest one is in the middle, but I have not investigated deeply. My own approach is different.

fwiw : simplified discriminant is 4A(B+C-A)-(B-C)^2

@FirstNameLastName note that B+C-A is the square of the distance of the survey point from the fourth corner of the square, so there’s some nice symmetry here. Here, A = b^2 in the figure in the OP, but B and C are permutations of a^2 and c^2

@Pranay : thanks for explaining ... next week or so I will add references to my solution in OP. The formula for the fourth corner is useful indeed


 Line $b$ divides the $π/2$ angle in two parts, say $α$ below it and $π/2-α$ above it.


 Let $x$ be the length of the sides of the square. The cosine rule states that $cos(α)=\frac{a^2-(x^2+b^2)}{2xb}$ and $sin(α)=cos(π/2-α)=\frac{c^2-(x^2+b^2)}{2xb}$.


 $cos(α)^2+sin(α)^2-1=0$ then leads to a quadratic equation for $x^2$ with roots $$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+c^2\pm\sqrt{(a^2+c^2)^2-4(b^4-b^2(a^2+c^2)+\frac{a^4+c^4}{2})}}{2}}$$ for $x$.


 Below is some Scala code.




import scala.math.pow

val pyth: (Double, Double) => Double = (z, y) => pow(z, 2.0) + pow(y, 2.0)

val x: (Double, Double, Double) => Double = (a, b, c) =>
  pow(
    (pyth(a, c) +
      pow(
        pow(pyth(a, c), 2.0) -
          4.0 * (pow(b, 4.0) - pow(b, 2.0) * pyth(a, c) + (pow(a, 4.0) + pow(c, 4.0)) / 2.0),
        1.0 / 2.0
      )) / 2.0,
    1.0 / 2.0
  )

@main def main(): Unit =

  println(x(5.0, 4.0, 3.0)) // should be approximately 5.6539039209289506

  println(x(pow(5.0, 1.0/2.0), 2.0, 1.0)) // should be approximately 2.2360679774997902
```


formula is correct, I verified a few examples
